# Swift iOS - Add data as custom model containing custom model to Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift4

So I have two custom model classes. One is a `Story` and the other is `Page`. The Story contains multiple properties including an array of `pages`.

```
struct Story {

var name: String
var pages: [Page]
var tags: [String]
var likes: [String]
var isPrivate: Bool

var dictionary: [String: Any] {
    return [
        "name": name,
        "pages": pages,
        "tags": tags,
        "likes": likes,
        "isPrivate": isPrivate,
    ]
}

struct Page {

let thumbnail: String
let image: String?
let video: String?

var dictionary: [String: Any] {
    return [
        "thumbnail": thumbnail,
        "image": image as Any,
        "video": video as Any
    ]
}
```

When I upload to Firebase I basically I want the pages object to be a subcollection within the Story object. But I am confused on how I would correctly do this in such a way that I can have the models properly map and decode from the Firebase Response.

The only way I can think of doing this is to create a Story on the database, get a callback with the ID and then create the page within that. The problem is that my `Story` model wouldn't then include the custom `Page` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to write to Firestore to get the auto-generated Id of that document. Firestore auto generates Ids on the client (it's a combination of timestamp and random).

Second, you may want to consider adding a property to `Story` that carries the array of pages in dictionary format:

```
struct Page {

    let thumbnail: String
    let image: String?
    let video: String?

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "thumbnail": thumbnail,
            "image": image as Any,
            "video": video as Any
        ]
    }

}

struct Story {

    var name: String
    var pages: [Page]
    var pagesData: [[String: Any]] // I added this for convenience
    var tags: [String]
    var likes: [String]
    var isPrivate: Bool

    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "name": name,
            "pages": pages,
            "tags": tags,
            "likes": likes,
            "isPrivate": isPrivate,
        ]
    }

}
```

Then create your pages as normal:

```
let page1 = Page(thumbnail: "abc", image: nil, video: nil)
let page2 = Page(thumbnail: "xyz", image: nil, video: nil)
```

Create a story and inject the pages into it, including the datafied version:

```
let story = Story(name: "Story", pages: [page1, page2], pagesData: [page1.dictionary, page2.dictionary], tags: ["kiwi", "mango"], likes: ["x", "y"], isPrivate: false)
```

Use Firestore to generate a random identifier:

```
let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("someCollection").document()
let docId = docRef.documentID
```

You can now inject this identifier into every object before writing to Firestore if you need them to share it.

Create the data object that will be written to Firestore:

```
let data: [String: Any] = [

    "name": story.name,
    "pages": story.pagesData
    // etc

]
```

In the backend, the `pages` field will be an array of maps.

Then just write the data to Firestore:

```
docRef.setData(data) { (error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(" \(error)")
    } else {
        print("")
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. Just wondering, how I might do it without `PagesData` and how that might affect the way in which I fetch the data and map it to the model?

Comment: If you omit the `pagesData` property from the model object, then just write it out like so: `"pages": [page1.dictionary, page2.dictionary]`. This has no impact on how you read from Firestore and use downloaded data to instantiate your custom objects. Do you know how to instantiate a custom object, like your `Story`, by passing in a `[String: Any]` dictionary into its initializer?

Answer (score 11):

For what it's worth, anyone winding up here via Google looking for custom data model handling + Swift + Firebase should check out this feature of Firebase using the `Codable` protocol.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects

Specifically this gives you access to a special `setData` call that looks like `document("LA").setData(from: city)`.

You should not need the extra import anymore in Firebase v7.3+ so that's awesome! If you're still on v6 or older, you need it.

If you don't have access to this function in your code, it's because you need to `import FirebaseFirestoreSwift` which are special extensions for Swift prior to v7.0.

Comment: such a big mistake by firebase docs, I spent so long on figuring this out, thanks for your answer, I thought they have deprecated this use case with `from` parameter, writing all dictionary mapping is such a pain in the ass.

Comment: Adding that import worked at first. I'd swear the error went away and I compiled and ran the tests at least once. 
But now it just says `No such module 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'` without making any further changes!

Comment: You also need `pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'` in your Podfile, or however you brought Firebase into your project.

Comment: @jb8618 Thank-you sir

Comment: Just an update: When you add pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift' you'll see that Firebase version will be downgraded to 6.34.0, and many other dependencies will be downgraded as well. My guess is that adding that line is no longer necessary. I have access to .setData method without that line in my Podfile with Firebase version 7.3.0.

Comment: @Ted Sweet. I'll update my comment! thanks for this. The codes always be evolving...